# Starting Facebook with IntentUriHandler not working anymore

Tags: android, kotlin

Does anyone know why this is not working anymore:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("fb://profile/$facebook_id")
startActivity(context!!, Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), null)
```

This is the error I got:

```
FB URI = fb://profile/437945186262780
2023-10-16 16:52:19.693   605-959   ActivityTaskManager     system_server                        I  START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fb://profile/... cmp=com.facebook.katana/.IntentUriHandler} from uid 10173
2023-10-16 16:52:19.928 12820-12820 fb4a.RageShakeDetector  com.facebook.katana                  W  onResume: com.facebook.katana.IntentUriHandler@609ec48
2023-10-16 16:52:19.946 12820-12820 fb4a.RageShakeDetector  com.facebook.katana                  W  onPause: com.facebook.katana.IntentUriHandler@609ec48
2023-10-16 16:52:20.221 12820-12820 fb4a.SlowAppComponent   com.facebook.katana                  E  0ms: IntentUriHandler instantiating…
2023-10-16 16:52:20.221 12820-12820 fb4a.SlowAppComponent   com.facebook.katana                  E  Main thread was blocked for 490ms in the foreground starting with IntentUriHandler
```

This is the "error" screen:

[image]

The fb://profile/$facebook_id is correct and tested.

Can this be the problem:

```
Main thread was blocked for 280ms in the foreground starting with IntentUriHandler
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? The log messages suggest that Facebook is processing your request.

Comment: I added the screen. The fb uri is correct and tested.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly define in the manifest file packages of apps you are going to call, e.g.:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.translate"/>
</queries>
```

It was introduced in Android 11 (API 30). Also others causes are possible. It will require more research to figure out a root cause.

[Ref. Android docs: queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element)

[Ref. Android docs: Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11)

Comment: Thx, I’ll try this out. Sounds reasonable. In Xcode/swift you have to do the samen.

Comment: So I need to add: com.facebook.katana

Comment: Didn't help ;-(

Comment: I have reviewed your updated question. Blocking the main a thread is a bad practice, but it should not terminate your app until your blocking code do not reach 5 seconds threshold. Regarding the root cause of the issue, from top of my mind I do not have any other thoughts, I am not familiar with facebook katana SDK and have to investigate the issue by my own. At this moment and in the closest future I am not ready to dive deeper into this.

Comment: Thx, for your time. I don’t use the katana SDK. And used this code for some years without a problem.